# Executing SSH with the Linux/Unix at command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I place this ssh call in the following a shell script on our Linux box named "tstz" and then call it with the linux "at" command in order to schedule it for later execution.

tstz script:

```
#! /bin/ksh
/usr/bin/ssh -tt <remote windows server> pmcmds ${fl} ${wf} < /dev/null >/tmp/test1.log 2>&1
```

at command syntax:

at -f tstz now + 1 minute

The ssh call executes remote command as expected, but the ssh connection closes immediately before the remote command has completed. I need the connection to stay open until the remote command has completed and then return control to the tstz script with an exit status.

This is the error I get in the /tmp/test1.log:

tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
^[[2JConnection to dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him closed.^M

NOTE: When using the "at" command to schedule tstz, if I don't use -tt, the ssh command will not execute the remoted command "pmcmds ${fl} ${wf}". I believe this is because a terminal is required. I can however run tstz from the Linux command prompt in the foreground without the -tt on the ssh command line and it runs as expected.

Any help would be greately appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: /usr/bin/ssh -tt <remote windows server> pmcmds ${fl} ${wf} < /dev/null >/tmp/test1.log 2>&1

Comment: your redirections are being processed by the local shell. Single or dbl-quote what you need in your command to be executed on the remote shell, so it is seen as a command to the remote shell. Good luck.

Comment: I tried both 'pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TESTa' and "pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TESTa" Neither worked without the -tt option and when I use -tt, the ssh command still exits immediately after launching the remote command.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to specify a command to execute on the REMOTE machine after successfully connecting to the server, not on LOCAL machine.

I use following command

```
ssh -i "key.pem"  ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  -t 'command; bash -l -c "sudo su"'
```

where  you should replace "sudo su"  with your own command, I guess with "pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TESTa"

So, try to issue, maybe

```
/usr/bin/ssh -tt <remote windows server> 'command; bash -l -c "pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TESTa"'
```

P.S.  I have discovered interesting service on google called "explainshell"
which helped me to understand that "command;" keyword is crucial inside quotes.